# Create a tailwindcss responsive grid with 2 colums: one fixed one stretched

Tags: tailwind-css

I need to manage a tailwid grid with a column with fixed width, and another one with a stretched width.

Please show this sample: https://play.tailwindcss.com/jnWKg6hTyG

In the sample i can manage a fixed column for the button "Show" using `w-12` in the button class, but the "Password" input does not stretch.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your question but if grid isn't strict requirement then consider using flexbox for this.

IMHO flex is better in these situations.
Example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/gcMrxejDQw